# What are the privacy pros and cons of using a public DNS server vs. your own?

Tags: privacy, dns, google, server, user-tracking

Whether I'm using a normal internet connection setup, or tunnelling it through an anonymizing VPN or through TOR, what information of mine is revealed to whatever DNS server that I choose (e.g. [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/))?

Would I gain any privacy benefits if I created and used my own DNS server (either on my own dedicated linux server on the internet or on my own PC system locally)?

But on the other hand, might there be any privacy *disadvantage* to using my own DNS server that I'm not thinking of? (Like some form of leakage/attack whereby the DNS server you use is exposed to some website - and if you use something like TOR or a VPN, the IP address of your *own* DNS server has been leaked and so your anonymity is still compromised, in that way?)

I am not so concerned about *security* (for example someone hacking my (amateurly-protected) DNS server and redirecting domains to phishing IPs to steal my information or identity), but mainly *privacy*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, if your own DNS server is on your LAN, it'll still be forwarding requests to other DNS servers, revealing your request to them.  So the remote DNS server will see your IP rather than the public DNS service IP.

As far as TOR is concerned, you can [route DNS over TOR](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/Preventing_Tor_DNS_Leaks) which will make the TOR exit gateway the only one seen by the public DNS provider.

If you're curious about what Google Public DNS does with your information, I suggest [reading the privacy policy](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/privacy).  You could, of course, assume that Google lies in their privacy policies, depending on your level of paranoia.

Comment: Sure Google lies. Facebook lied too http://blogs.lawyers.com/2012/08/facebooks-privacy-policy-was-a-lie-says-the-ftc/ I'm sure NSA loves DNS requests ;)